# Find mathematical complement of a set of intervals with SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, intervals

I'm pondering over the following problem which needs to be solved via SQL. Let there be an interval [a, b] of natural numbers, and a (finite) set of intervals A that are all subsets of [a, b]. We want to determine the complement auf A, that is, a set of intervals B such that A + B = [a, b] and A and B are pairwise disjoint.

For example: Given [a, b] = the days of 2017 ("all days"), and the intervals March-June, April, April-July and November ("possible days"). Now produce the intervals jan-feb, aug-oct and dec ("impossible days"). All intervals are resp. should be defined via start date and end date.

I tried the following. Produce a calender of 2017 and check for every day if it is contained in neither of the intervals. From these days, construct the corresponding intervals. So far it seems complicated and I'm starting to think that this solution approach is somewhat unlucky with SQL. But maybe it's just my implementation. What do you think? Would you maybe know a better way?

Greetings from Frankfurt,

Johannes

Comment: Your solution is a very sqlish way of doing things like that. Break complex data into atomary pieces, manipulate those atoms and construct  the aggregates back.

Comment: That's similar to approaches i've used in the past.  As long as you keep the upper and lower bouns of the intervals in seperate columns and use the `between` function it works pretty effeciently

Comment: I'm sorry, and maybe it's the lack of sleep, but I really don't understand the question at all. Sample data as DDL + DML and desired results usually make the question much more understandable.

Comment: You have a point there. I'll try to be less abstract the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're working with a known fixed range then you can easily find the candidates to be a start or end that is outside of any current interval. And then just pair those up based on date order:

```
declare @RangeStart date
declare @RangeEnd date
select @RangeStart = '20170101',@RangeEnd = '20171231'

declare @intervals table (
    StartAt date not null,
    EndAt date not null
)
insert into @intervals (StartAt,EndAt) values
('20170301','20170630'),
('20170401','20170430'),
('20170401','20170731'),
('20171101','20171130')

;With Starts as (
    select
        @RangeStart as StartDT
    where
        not exists (select * from @intervals i where @RangeStart between i.StartAt and i.EndAt) --Start outside an interval
    union all
    select
        DATEADD(day,1,i1.EndAt)
    from
        @intervals i1
            left join
        @intervals i2
            on
                DATEADD(day,1,i1.EndAt) between i2.StartAt and i2.EndAt --No succeeding interval
    where
        i2.EndAt is null
), Ends as (
    select
        @RangeEnd as EndDT
    where
        not exists (select * from @intervals i where @RangeEnd between i.StartAt and i.EndAt) --End outside an interval
    union all
    select
        DATEADD(day,-1,i1.StartAt)
    from
        @intervals i1
            left join
        @intervals i2
            on
                DATEADD(day,-1,i1.StartAt) between i2.StartAt and i2.EndAt --No preceding interval
    where
        i2.StartAt is null
), OrderedStarts as (
    select StartDT,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartDT) as rn
    from Starts where StartDT between @RangeStart and @RangeEnd
), OrderedEnds as (
    select EndDT,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EndDt) as rn
    from Ends where EndDT between @RangeStart and @RangeEnd
)

select
    os.StartDT,oe.EndDT
from
    OrderedStarts os
        inner join
    OrderedEnds oe
        on
            os.rn = oe.rn
```

Result:

```
StartDT    EndDT
---------- ----------
2017-01-01 2017-02-28
2017-08-01 2017-10-31
2017-12-01 2017-12-31
```

That is - valid start dates are the start of our range or the day after any other interval, provided that doesn't overlap with another interval. Similarly for valid ends.

Comment: Thanks Damien! This worked well! Just a minor adjustments I replaced the two "union all"-operators with union-operators resp. This way, the number of start dates always equals the number of end dates.